Static methods in Java interfaces to be implemented by classes that implement the interface
I know that it is possible to define static methods in Java interfaces that are bound to the interface itself. However, I would like to define the signature of a static method to be implemented by each class that implements the interface. This would allow to use the design pattern called Static Creation Method.
I cannot define a static method in the interface because the implementation depends on the concrete class. Also, I can not just pretend that my classes will have the Static Creation Method, because I want to call the method recursively as in the Rust example that comes next.
I can do this in Rust:
fn main() {
    Double::zero().print();
    Complex::<Double>::zero().print();
    Dual::<Double>::zero().print();
    Dual::<Complex::<Double>>::zero().print();
    Complex::<Dual::<Double>>::zero().print();
}


trait SetElement<T: SetElement<T>>
{
    fn to_string( &self ) -> String;
    
    fn print( &self )
    {
        println!( "{}" , self.to_string() );
    }
}


trait AdditiveUnitalMagma<T: AdditiveUnitalMagma<T>>: SetElement<T>
{
    fn zero() -> T;
}


struct Double
{
    x: f64,
}


impl SetElement<Double> for Double
{
    fn to_string( &self ) -> String
    {
        self.x.to_string()
    }
}


impl AdditiveUnitalMagma<Double> for Double
{
    fn zero() -> Double
    {
        Double{ x: 0.0 }
    }
}


struct Complex<T>
{
    x: T,
    y: T,
}


impl<T: SetElement<T>> SetElement<Complex<T>> for Complex<T>
{
    fn to_string( &self ) -> String
    {
        "(".to_owned() + &self.x.to_string() + ") + i (" + &self.y.to_string() + ")"
    }
}


impl<T: AdditiveUnitalMagma<T>> AdditiveUnitalMagma<Complex<T>> for Complex<T>
{
    fn zero() -> Complex<T>
    {
        Complex{ x: T::zero() , y: T::zero() }
    }
}


struct Dual<T>
{
    a: T,
    b: T,
}


impl<T: SetElement<T>> SetElement<Dual<T>> for Dual<T>
{
    fn to_string( &self ) -> String
    {
        "(".to_owned() + &self.a.to_string() + ") + epsilon (" + &self.b.to_string() + ")"
    }
}


impl<T: AdditiveUnitalMagma<T>> AdditiveUnitalMagma<Dual<T>> for Dual<T>
{
    fn zero() -> Dual<T>
    {
        Dual{ a: T::zero() , b: T::zero() }
    }
}


Do you know if there is a way to do something similar in Java? This is, to be able to use the Static Creation Method recursively as:
public static void main(String[] args) {
    Double.zero().print();
    Complex<Double>.zero().print();
    Dual<Double>.zero().print();
    Dual<Complex<Double>>.zero().print();
    Complex<Dual<Double>>.zero().print();
}

Is there a better way to provide similar functionality? Is there a reason for Java avoiding this kind of implementation, or is it just bad language design?

Static methods in Java just don't work that way.  They aren't inherited and therefore they don't produce any kind of "signature" that can be exploited later.  If I understand correctly what you are asking, I'm not familiar with Rust.

@markspace static methods are inherited, at least according Java Language Specification 8.4.8. Inheritance, Overriding, and Hiding: "A class C inherits from its direct superclass type D all concrete methods m (both static and instance) ..."

There is no such thing as the class that implements the interface. Anyone can implement any interface. Which of the many possible implementations do you want to use?

What would be the benefit of such enforcement?  Your example main method doesn’t use polymorphism, as far as I can tell.  Explicit static zero() methods in the Double, Complex, and Dual classes would work just as well regardless of whether those classes were forced to implement those methods through some kind of theoretical static inheritance.

@user85421 Thanks for that, I guess I had that wrong (is that a recent change?).  But I note that from that same section: A class does not inherit private or static methods from its superinterface types.  So there's one type of inheritance out.  And from the section following that one: It is a compile-time error if the overridden method, mA, is a static method. So static inherited methods can't be overridden, which limits their usefulness.

@n.m.couldbeanAI of course, there could be as many as we want. I will edit to reflect that fact. Answering your question, I want to be able to use any class that implements the interface.

@VGR the benefit would be that one can use any class implementing the AdditiveUnitalMagma interface for the generics in Complex, Dual, or any other class with generics. Think about a Matrix class for example. Suddenly you can define a Matrix<Double> or Matrix<Complex<Double>>, ... and one can have a Static Creation Method zero that initializes all elements to the right value. This is only possible if the class that is taken as generic knows how to call its zero static method. Look at the implementations of zero for Complex or Dual in the example.

But people, the question is not about replicating the code of the example. I know that Java does not provide the means to do it. It is about finding a way to make something similar. Or if nothing similar can be done in Java, then reasoning about why. Is it a feature of the language because writing such code is a bad idea (please provide an explanation if that is the case); or is it a limitation of the language due to bad design?

Something similar to what? Something similar to something that doesn’t exist also doesn’t exist. Your question is unclear.

Oh so you want Java interfaces to work like traits. They don't.  The two concepts are rather different. Interfaces specify how objects must behave, traits specify how types must behave.

@n.m.couldbeanAI thanks for your comment. It was really enlightening written in such a simple way. I think this, along with VGR's answer, gives me a direction to keep thinking.

If I understand your question correctly, this is normally solved using factory classes, instead of static factory methods:
sealed abstract class ValueFactory<T>
permits DoubleFactory,
        ComplexFactory,
        DualFactory {

    abstract T zero();
}

final class DoubleFactory
extends ValueFactory<Double> {
    @Override
    Double zero() { /* ... */ }
}

final class ComplexFactory<U>
extends ValueFactory<Complex<U>> {
    ComplexFactory(Supplier<? extends U> zeroElementCreator) { /* ... */ }

    @Override
    Complex<U> zero() { /* ... */ }
}

final class DualFactory<U>
extends ValueFactory<Dual<U>> {
    DualFactory(Supplier<? extends U> zeroElementCreator) { /* ... */ }

    @Override
    Dual<U> zero() { /* ... */ }
}


Thanks for this answer. I think I see what you are doing, and this seems to be closer to what I wanted than any other thing I had thought about. For example, instead of Matrix4x4<Complex<Double>>.zero() we would do Matrix4x4Factory<Complex<Double>> myFactory = new Matrix4x4Factory<Complex<Double>>( ComplexFactory<Double>( DoubleFactory() ) ); Matrix4x4<Complex<Double>> myMatrix4x4 = myFactory.zero(), right?.

However, I am not sure if this is what I want. This seems to be breaking encapsulation. First, we would have to make the constructor of Double, Complex, and Dual public so that the factories can access them. I would rather prefer a private constructor and then being able to call methods such as Matrix4x4<Dual<Fraction<Integer>>>.zero() or Matrix4x4<Complex<Double>>.one().

Second, there is no information in each class about it being an AdditiveUnitalMagma or a MultiplicativeUnitalMagma. Which classes have a "zero" element? Which ones have a "one" element? It would not be possible to see looking at a single class (take Complex as an example) if that class can have a "zero" element or not; we would always need to check the permits in the factories.

Third, only with "zero" and "one" we already need 2 different factories, each one implementing the methods to create a "zero" or a "one" for each of the classes. Each time we create a new class that has a "zero" element, we would need to modify the factories (think about a new Fraction class; it has "zero" and "one" elements...)

But I think that a factory might be the right direction. This answer helps me to keep thinking. Thanks again!

You could always add static factory methods to ValueFactory, like static ValueFactory<Double> newDoubleFactory(), instead of making each subclass’s constructor public.  But if zero() is an optional functionality, it strongly suggests that inheritance is not the right tool for the task.
